# JTattoo to make Round buttons in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I have a problem with my calculator Gui, I used Jtatto  to Create a Calculator with Round Buttons

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
```

But the buttons became looked like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this (i mean without any lines inside them)

Comment: Are you referring to the button borders?  If so, try `setBorder(null)` on a button and see if that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs with the newer versions of JDK since the look and feel tools are less frequently used. I currently use JDK v1.8 on NetBeans and this issue isn't there atleast for the jbuttons.
Although it's not generally recommended, you can try with the previous version of JDK to see if the issue persists or not
If you are using Apache NetBeans you can check which version of JDK NetBeans is using by selecting Tools ⇾ Java Platforms from the NetBeans menu
Further I would recommend you to either use Smart Look & Feel instead of aluminium or use the JDK v1.8 for better compatibility.

For more information you can read this article below :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jbutton-with-rounded-edges/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).